# ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated_endpoints'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is my code :

```
 from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


model = load_model(filepath=r'/Users/fatenaldossary/Desktop/breast-cancer-classification/breast-cancer-classification/saved_model.h5')
print(model.summary(), '\n')


img_path ='/Users/fatenaldossary/Desktop/breast-cancer-classification/breast-cancer-classification/datasets/original/8867/0/8867_idx5_x101_y501_class0.png'
# We preprocess the image into a 4D tensor
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(48, 48, 1)) 
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)
# Remember that the model was trained on inputs
# that were preprocessed in the following way:
img_tensor /= 255.
# Its shape is (1, 150, 150, 3)
print(img_tensor.shape)


plt.imshow(img_tensor[0])
plt.show() 

prediction = model.predict(img_tensor)
print(prediction)
```

but the output is

ImportError: cannot import name 'deprecated_endpoints'

anyone have any solution

Comment: edit your post to include the full traceback

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.